# How to compare two robot results on Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, robotframework

Suppose I run 100 testcases on Jenkins using Robot Framework on day 1 and 10 cases are failing.
And on the next day I run the same 100 cases but now 15 cases are failing.

So I want to know what are the new test cases are failing on day 2. Can any one suggest a way to do this?

Comment: did you try Robot Jenkins Plugin? It has such feature - showing "age" of failing test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way would be to diff the two generated output.xml files and see what is different. Several command line tools can help you with that.

If this is one of those more less frequest jobs then you may want to try the `robotdiff` python script that can be downloaded from [Robotframework site](https://bitbucket.org/robotframework/robottools/src/master/robotdiff/). It does exactly what you want.

In case this request is something that happens more frequently, and the comparison may be more complex, then storing the results in a database may be the best way forward. Then using SQL you can extract the comparison you need. [DbBot](https://github.com/robotframework/DbBot) converts the output.xml files into the database.